# How do I unlock the 6th world in EscapeVektor?

Tags: escapevektor

In *EscapeVektor* (Wii), I've gotten a star in every level and all 5 worlds, but I am unable to unlock the path to the 6th world, which I believe is grayed out and directly above the first world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will only unlock after you buy future chapters(greedy!) or own their previous game "Pop". hope this helps

Comment: If you are correct, that's quite evil! :(